# ADSI(ADsOpenObject ) always binds to a particular domain and to a specific user

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ldap, adsi

Currently I am working on existing vc++ dll, that uses `ADsOpenObject` method to bind the domain details. Whenever i am executing the code it is always pointing to a specific domain like 'picTest.com' and for a particular user, whoever is the user or whatever is the domain it always bind to the same domain and user. Below is the code snippet:

```
hr = ADsOpenObject(szBindPath,
                          NULL,
                         NULL,
                         ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, // Use Secure Authentication
                         IID_IADs,                   (void**)&pObject);
```

The above code is very straight forward, I believe the domain and the user is configured somewhere. I have look for any entry for registry and environment variable, didn't find any clue.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the MSDN article about [ADsOpenObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772238(v=vs.85).aspx):

> A C/C++ client calls the ADsOpenObject helper function to bind to an
>   ADSI object, using the user name and password supplied as credentials
>   for the appropriate directory service. If lpszUsername and
>   lpszPassword are NULL and ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION is set, ADSI binds
>   to the object using the security context of the calling thread, which
>   is either the security context of the user account under which the
>   application is running or of the client user account that the calling
>   thread impersonates.

In other words. because u specified `NULL` for the user and password, the current user executing the software is used to bind. And because you didn't specify a specific domain controller in your ldap path (Like `ldap://DC01.example.local/CN=something,DC=example,dc=local`) it binds to a DC of its own choosing.